# Getting Error when adding an async function on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to add `async` method on `node.js v6.11` but i, getting `Unexpected identifier` error.

```
let fs = require('fs');
let Config = require('../somefolders/config.js');

module.exports = class SomeClassName {
  constructor(id = null) {

  }

  //Some other methods

  static async test1234(param) {

  }

  //Some other Static methods
}
```

This is the error We are getting:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5TUX.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, markup, and error messages **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I am using v6.11. Thanks alot @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Yup, that's seriously out-of-date. :-) Current is v12, current LTS is v10: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the screenshot tells us you're using an old version of Node.js that doesn't have `async`/`await` support. Node.js has had `async`/`await` for years, but if I go back to v7, I can replicate exactly the error in your screenshot.

If you update to an up-to-date version of Node.js (or even a vaguely-recent one), that code is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

use Node version 7.6 or above. async/await added in ES2017.